# npm http-server downloads index.html instead of serving

Tags: html, http, npm, server

I am using http-server with ssl certificate in order to test facebook instant games. However, while server is running `localhost` makes my browser download `index.html` file instead of actually serving it in a browser. The problem occures in chrome, but microsoft edge seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/

instead of localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

I found out this problem only occurs in Chrome, edge seemed to work fine, so I decided to clear browsing data in the chrome settings and tried again and surprisingly it doesn't download `index.html` from `localhost:8080` anymore! This method solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could arise due to header statement try removing header while writing code like if your code looks like

```js
http.createServer( (req, res) => {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});// header
   res.end('Hello World\n');  // body
}).listen(8081);
```

Then you can change this to -

```js
http.createServer( (req, res) => {
   res.end('Hello World\n');  // body
}).listen(8081);
```

This would probably fix your issue.